# DB_File.pm Perl под Windows

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, кто знает - я установила Active Perl 5.16 на Windows7
Необходимо работать с БД, с DB_File.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Perl1

 use strict;
 use DB_File;

 my %hash;

 tie %hash, "DB_File", "myDB"
 or die "Could not create file 'myDB': $!\n";

 $hash{'key1'} = 'value1';
 $hash{'key2'} = 'value2';
 $hash{'key3'} = 'value3';

 untie %hash;
```

Пишет, что не найден модуль DB_File.pm.
Что можно сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте CPAN.pm. Позволяет искать и устанавливать модули с CPAN (Comprehensive Perl Arcive Network). Смотреть perldoc CPAN, там написано, как вызывать. Правда под виндами далеко не всё работает (компилятора с C по умолчанию в системе нет).

Answer (score 2):

Для ActiveState Perl можно использовать ppm:

```
ppm install DB_File
```

либо cpan:

```
cpan DB_File
```

Либо ppm GUI. Более подробно [здесь](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl).